# Error con i18n en Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, i18n

Mi problema es que cuando intento cambiar el nombre de la constante, donde tengo el contenido para traducir me deja de funcionar.

```
export const messages = {
en: {
    section: {
        home: 'Home',
        about: 'About',
        login: 'Login',
        register: 'Register',
    }
},
es: {
    section: {
        hello: 'Inicio',
        about: 'Acerca de',
        login: 'Iniciar sesión',
        register: 'Registrarse',
    }
}
```

}

Si cambio el nombre de messages a "aaa" por ejemplo, ya no me funciona. Obviamente, también cambio el nombre en el main.js

```
//Lang
import { messages } from '@/lang/sections_menu'


const i18n = createI18n({
   locale: 'en',
   fallbackLocale: 'en',
   messages
 })
```

Es decir si cambio messages a "aaa" ya no me funciona por alguna razon. Así la llamo desde la vista

```
$t('section.home')
```

Y no puede ser un problema de nombre de archivos, ni nada por el estilo, porque sino, no me funcionaría nunca. No se, si tengo que cambiarla en algún otro lado también, pero no recuerdo tener alguna referencia a esa constante en ningún otro archivo.